# How to set indent to 4 spaces in nxml-mode?

Tags: indentation, nxml

I wanted to indent my XML files with 4 spaces.
I tried to google it, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666513/how-to-indent-4-spaces-under-sgml-mode) and [this one](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingHtml).
But they seem pretty old and/or didn't help me.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492/pretty-printing-xml-files-on-emacs) is great about how to pretty print XML files, but gives no hint how to set indent to a specific value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 23):

I finally found it in [this issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/5483).

```
(setq nxml-child-indent 4 nxml-attribute-indent 4)
```